# what is the mapper and reducer that are used in computeSVD() function?

Tags: apache-spark, svd

i am new to Map reduce and i want to do some research to compute svd using mapreduce.

- the code side : i have found `computeSVD` a **pyspark** function and it uses **mapreduce** as said in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71938367/does-this-function-computesvd-use-mapreduce-in-pyspark) .
- the theory side : **what is the mapper and reducer that are used in computeSVD() function** ?

my code

```
findspark.init('C:\spark\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7')
conf=SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[*]")
conf.setAppName('firstapp')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
rows = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=float) # data.txt is a (m rows x n cols) matrix m>n
rows = sc.parallelize(rows)
mat = RowMatrix(rows)
svd = mat.computeSVD(5, computeU=True)
```

i would highely appriciate any help.

Comment: !. One question at a time, please. 2. Show your code.

Comment: @clvrmnky i updated my question and i added the code, and my only question is : **what is the mapper and reducer that are used in computeSVD() ?** since it is a **predefined function** i couldn't know where exactly is the map and the reduce on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71938367/437212 might have some hints

Comment: yes its where i knew that `computeSVD()` uses **mapreduce** , and the source code link was posted , but i honestly couldn't understend it well , it is complicated for a begginer like.  here is the code link https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.scala#L328

Comment: Spark doesn't use Hadoop mapreduce. You don't find mapper and reducer "classes" anywhere. You might find RDD.map and RDD.reduce _functions_ internal to the dataframe methods, but that's not the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in [this function](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.scala#L702) the usage of `mapPartitions` and `reduceByKey` from the RDD object, which do something similar to MapReduce, but is not the same library as Hadoop Mapreduce